# 9 path not stretch correctly

Tags: android, nine-patch

I know there is a lots of other questions about this but I try all of them and nothing works for me.
I want to create a button with 9 patch background. This is my 9 patch image :

[image]

I create this with draw9patch.bat in android sdk :

[image]

And I use this xml to create my button :

```
<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="New Button"
  android:id="@+id/btnTest"
  android:background="@drawable/ic_btn2" />
```

But the result is weird :

[image]

For test purpose I download some 9 patches and replace them with my image but those images have this problem too. I use android studio 2. what cause this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the file's name ends with `.9.png`.

Comment: Thank you, I miss that part